# Supplying email attribute in SAML response to Azure AD API Application

Tags: azure-api-apps, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to receive the email address attribute in the SAML response for an Azure AD API application, I've been able to modify the manifest json to supply group membership - and receive other attributes like name/upn but don't receive email, is there a way to configure this in the manifest? (The SSO application is a jira plugin)

Thanks

Comment: Did you read this article ? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-token-and-claims/

Comment: @J, Could you set your SAML configuration on Azure ACS? If yes, I recommend you can refer to this document and set the input claim Type as emailaddress. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/privatecloud/2014/01/17/setting-up-windows-azure-active-directory-acs-to-provide-identities-to-windows-azure-pack/